# xmpp: ConnectionClosedOn Error! Parser got END_DOCUMENT event

Tags: android, ejabberd

I'm trying too login to the android app that i have created whose authentication will be done using the username and password registered in ejabberd. The connection is successfully established but i'm not abe to login. It gives an error namely - 
"ConnectionClosedOn Error! Parser got END_DOCUMENT event. This could happen e.g. if the server closed the connection without sending a closing stream element"

The log is:

```
04-15 19:27:45.052 31421-31421/com.synergy.allie.ecm D/calling xmpp connect: started
```

04-15 19:27:45.052 31421-31749/com.synergy.allie.ecm D/Connect() Function: =>connecting....

04-15 19:27:45.072 31421-31421/com.synergy.allie.ecm D/LoginActivity: onServiceConnected

04-15 19:27:45.102 31421-31751/com.synergy.allie.ecm I/System.out: 07:27:45 PM SENT (0): http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>

04-15 19:27:45.102 31421-31752/com.synergy.allie.ecm I/System.out: 07:27:45 PM RECV (0): http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='284868730' from='allen' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>

04-15 19:27:45.102 31421-31752/com.synergy.allie.ecm I/System.out: 07:27:45 PM RECV (0): http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='SLr01mk3X636tk4sDXYXPXsNNcE='/>http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/>PLAINDIGEST-MD5SCRAM-SHA-1

04-15 19:27:45.142 31421-31749/com.synergy.allie.ecm D/xmpp: Connected!

04-15 19:28:45.102 31421-31752/com.synergy.allie.ecm W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
                                                                               org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: Parser got END_DOCUMENT event. This could happen e.g. if the server closed the connection without sending a closing stream element
                                                                                   at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1148)
                                                                                   at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
                                                                                   at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

04-15 19:28:45.112 31421-31752/com.synergy.allie.ecm D/xmpp: ConnectionClosedOn Error! Parser got END_DOCUMENT event. This could happen e.g. if the server closed the connection without sending a closing stream element

```
public class MyXMPP 
{
public static boolean connected = false;
public boolean loggedin = false;
public static boolean isconnecting = false;
public static boolean isToasted = true;
private boolean chat_created = false;
private String serverAddress;
public static XMPPTCPConnection connection;
public static String loginUser;
public static String passwordUser;
Gson gson;
MyService context;
public static MyXMPP instance = null;
public static boolean instanceCreated = false;
public org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat Mychat;
ChatManagerListenerImpl mChatManagerListener;
MMessageListener mMessageListener;
Boolean logon;

public MyXMPP(MyService context, String serverAdress, String logiUser,
              String passwordser) {
    this.serverAddress = serverAdress;
    this.loginUser = logiUser;
    this.passwordUser = passwordser;
    this.context = context;
    init();

}

public static MyXMPP getInstance(MyService context, String server,
                                 String user, String pass) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyXMPP(context, server, user, pass);
        instanceCreated = true;
    }
    return instance;
}


String text = "";
String mMessage = "", mReceiver = "";
static {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // problem loading reconnection manager
    }
}

public void init() {
    gson = new Gson();
    mMessageListener = new MMessageListener(context);
    mChatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListenerImpl();
    initialiseConnection();

}

private void initialiseConnection() {

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setServiceName(serverAddress);
    config.setHost("***.***.***.***");
    config.setPort(5222);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
    connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

}

public void disconnect() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }).start();
}

public void connect(final String caller) {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected synchronized Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if (connection.isConnected())
                return false;
            isconnecting = true;
            if (isToasted)
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(context, caller + "Trying to establish a connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            Log.d("Connect() Function", caller + "=>connecting....");

            try {
                connection.connect();
                DeliveryReceiptManager dm = DeliveryReceiptManager
                        .getInstanceFor(connection);
                dm.setAutoReceiptMode(AutoReceiptMode.always);
                dm.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceiptReceived(final String fromid,
                                                  final String toid, final String msgid,
                                                  final Stanza packet) {

                    }
                });
                connected = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (isToasted)
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                            .post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    Toast.makeText(context, "(" + caller + ")" + "IOException: ",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                Log.e("(" + caller + ")", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "(" + caller + ")" + "SMACKException: ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("(" + caller + ")", "SMACKException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                if (isToasted)

                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                            .post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    Toast.makeText(context, "(" + caller + ")" + "XMPPException: ",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                Log.e("connect(" + caller + ")",
                        "XMPPException: " + e.getMessage());

            }
            return isconnecting = false;
        }
    };
    connectionThread.execute();
}

public void login()
{
    try
    {
        connection.login(loginUser, passwordUser);
        Log.i("LOGIN", "Praise Jesus! We're connected to the Xmpp server!");
        logon=true;
    }
    catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e)
    {
        logon=false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logon=false;
    }
}

private class ChatManagerListenerImpl implements ChatManagerListener {
    @Override
    public void chatCreated(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                            final boolean createdLocally) {
        if (!createdLocally)
            chat.addMessageListener(mMessageListener);

    }

}

public void sendMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage) {
    String body = gson.toJson(chatMessage);

    if (!chat_created) {
        Mychat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(chatMessage.receiver
                        + "@" + context.getString(R.string.server),
                mMessageListener);
        chat_created = true;
    }
    final Message message = new Message();
    message.setBody(body);
    message.setStanzaId(chatMessage.msgid);
    message.setType(Message.Type.chat);

    try {
        if (connection.isAuthenticated()) {

            Mychat.sendMessage(message);

        } else {

            login();
        }
    } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
        Log.e("xmpp.SendMessage()", "msg Not sent!-Not Connected!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("xmpp.SendMessage()", "msg Not sent!" + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public class XMPPConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener {
    @Override
    public void connected(final XMPPConnection connection) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "Connected!");
        connected = true;
        if (!connection.isAuthenticated()) {
            login();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(context, "ConnectionCLosed!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionCLosed!");
        connected = false;
        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ConnectionClosedOn Error!!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionClosedOn Error! "+arg0.getMessage());
        connected = false;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "Reconnectingin " + arg0);

        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "ReconnectionFailed!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionFailed!");
        connected = false;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(context, "REConnected!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionSuccessful");
        connected = true;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
        Log.d("xmpp", "Authenticated!");
        loggedin = true;

        ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addChatListener(
                mChatManagerListener);

        chat_created = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Connected!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
    }
}

private class MMessageListener implements ChatMessageListener {

    public MMessageListener(Context contxt) {
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                               final Message message) {
        Log.i("MyXMPP_MESSAGE_LISTENER", "Xmpp message received: '"
                + message);

        if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat
                && message.getBody() != null) {
            final ChatMessage chatMessage = gson.fromJson(
                    message.getBody(), ChatMessage.class);

            processMessage(chatMessage);
        }
    }

    private void processMessage(final ChatMessage chatMessage) {

        chatMessage.isMine = false;
        Chats.chatlist.add(chatMessage);
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Chats.chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

Comment: If you want the code of the connection pls let me know i'll post it also. Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide  connection code.

Comment: I added the connection code @SunilSingh

Comment: @AllenDaniel any solution found i am facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 public void initConnection(String user, String pass) throws XMPPException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub





        String SERVER_HOST = "192.168.1.199";
        int SERVER_PORT = 5222;
        String SERVICE_NAME = "Allen";
        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder connConfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
                    .builder();
            connConfig
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
            connConfig.setUsernameAndPassword(user, pass);
            connConfig.setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME);
            connConfig.setHost(SERVER_HOST);
            connConfig.setPort(SERVER_PORT).setCompressionEnabled(false);
            connConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
            connConfig.setConnectTimeout(25000);
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration configuration = connConfig.build();
            //  XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
            // XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
            // XMPPTCPConnection.setReplyToUnknownIqDefault(true);

            connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);
            connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
            connection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);
            connection.setReplyToUnknownIq(true);
            connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(25000);
            ReconnectionManager manager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            manager.setFixedDelay(15);
            ReconnectionManager.setDefaultReconnectionPolicy(ReconnectionManager.ReconnectionPolicy.FIXED_DELAY);
            manager.enableAutomaticReconnection();
            try {
                connection.connect();
                connection.login();


                //logIn();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same error Sunil Singh. What was the change that u made?

Comment: disable stream management  and check server side stream management is enabled?

Comment: provide ejabberd server configuration.

Comment: Here is the link to ejabberd.yml file. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Ea-hbs-OPnZjNaZnI1UGp2aDg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i have put up the ejabberd config, kindly check. Thank You.

Comment: @AllenDaniel add this connection and login  code  in your project if login success  then add your listeners.it is working and tested code.

Comment: can you please send me the ejabberd configuration and the android connection code to my email? "allend132@gmail.com"

Comment: it is not working again it is giving me the same error. Kindly help. Thank you.